# Custom Lookup Design

Tags: apex, lookup, configuration, lookup-filter

We have a Custom Object called "CaseEvents" which is a child to the parent standard object "Case".

Case-CaseEvents is 1:M relationship.

I would like to perform the following configuration

a) Add/Remove few fields that come as part of the standard lookup on CaseEvents

b) Apply a filter that will show only CaseEvents whose Type ="Immediate"

c) Allow another field as searchable For Eg : CaseEvents.Location to be searchable.

So if I type "Boston" I should be seeing all CaseEvents whose Location is "Boston".

Can someone tell me at a high level as how this can be done ?

Comment: Where are you performing these searches from that these are the requirements?  Are you adding lookups from other custom objects to CaseEvent?

Comment: This will be a lookup on the Case object..This lookup will show only those children CaseEvents records which are of "Immediate"type and where the user will be able to select one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Customizing Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_searchlayout.htm&language=en) for displaying specific fields, [Enabling Enhanced Lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable.htm&language=en) for filtering on fields other than Name, and [About Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en) for restricting search results.

A note on filtering in your case.  You'll want to make sure you include only CaseEvents that are related to your Case, not just those that have a certain Location value.